# Why postgres transaction wraparound happens at 2 billion instead of 4 billion transactionIDs

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

transaction id data type's possible values= 2^32= ~ 4 billion, then why does postgres declares a transaction wraparound and shuts down database at 2~31 2 billion transactions.

Comment: [Vacuum for wraparound](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND).

Answer (score 2):

That's because of what transaction IDs are considered future and which ones are in the past. If you view the space of transaction IDs as a circle, so that if you overflow at 2<sup>32</sup>, you start at 0 again, the separation between past and future is diametrically across from your current transaction ID. So if your transaction ID crosses 2<sup>31</sup>, low transaction IDs change from being in the distant past to being in the remote future. As a consequence, old, visible rows might suddenly become invisible, and long deleted rows that have never been vacuumed away could "rise from the dead". The reason for all that is that the visibility of a PostgreSQL row is governed by the system columns `xmin` and `xmax`, which are transaction IDs.

Let me add an example: if your current transaction ID is 42, then the future would consist of all transaction IDs between 42 and 2<sup>31</sup>+42, while the past are all transaction IDs between 2<sup>31</sup>+42 and 2<sup>32</sup>, plus all transaction IDs between 3 and 42 (the transaction IDs 0, 1 and 2 have a special meaning).

Comment: Can you help explain this as I am trying to wrap my head around this concept. If, for say, you're on transaction 2 billion. You can see, for example, the transaction that happened right before this one (assuming it was committed) - e.g. transaction 1.9999 billion. This is because 1.9999 billion is < 2 billion. However, when it wraps around to 0, even the most recent past transaction is now greater than 0, so it would not be visible. How is this resolved so the SELECT at transaction 0 (wrap around) can see transaction 1.999 billion?

Comment: I added an example that should make it clear.

Comment: When you say the current transaction id is 42, and the maximum transaction id allowed in the system is 2 billion (2^31), how can you have any transactions that are 2^31 + 42 as that's larger than the largest number allowed? Once you hit 2^31 (the largest number allowed), does it not start over at 0? I must be misunderstanding this concept somewhere.

Comment: A 4-byte unsigned integer can go up to 2^32-1.

Comment: So I'm still not following this logic. Let's say you're on transaction: 4294967295. You commit. The next transaction would be 0 (according to the statement that we can have up to 2^32-1 for the 4-byte unsigned integer). Tell me how a query with transaction 0 (the next transaction) sees the previous transaction: 4294967295 as the past and not the future?

Comment: As the past, of course. Except that 0 is not a valid transaction ID, but that is irrelevant for this consideration.

Comment: ok. What about transaction, say, 42 as stated above. How does it see itself as > 4294967295? I'm assuming the database simply compares the current transaction, 42, with others, e.g. 4294967295. However, if the algorithm for comparison is: take the current transaction and apply the following formula:  "use the current transaction and anything between  2^31 + 42 and 2^32 is visible", then this would make sense.

Comment: Think about it like that: internally, the transaction number is an 8-byte unsigned integer that never wraps around. The next 2^31 transactions are the future, the previous 2^31 transactions are the past. The leading 4 bytes are not stored in `xmin` and `xmax`.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres does not necessarily shut down the database after 2^31 transactions. It only does so if `VACUUM` is not run in between. If it runs regularly, you can execute as many transactions as you like (i.e. trillions) and the transaction-ids will happily wrap around without any problems.

Therefore, for each transaction-id there must be both, ids that compare lower, and ids that compare higher. To achieve that, Postgres uses *modulo 2^32 arithmetic*.

What `VACUUM` does is it marks rows from "old" transactions as "frozen", meaning they compare as older than all currently running transactions regardless of their actual id. This way the frozen rows are visible to all currently running transactions, even if simply comparing their transaction ids would suggest otherwise.

Comment: FYI this is done automatically by the autovacuum daemon, there is no need to manually run VACUUM. The exception being if a long running transaction kept tuples from being vacuumed. Then manual intervention maybe needed.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for this clarification. I rephrased the answer to not let it look like the user is forced to run VACUUM manually.

Answer (score -3):

That's because PostgreSQL does not implement unsigned integers since it's not in the SQL standard.

Comment: That is an answer to a different question and does not address the question of why wraparound is set at around 2 billion instead of ~4 billion. Read the link I posted in my comment for the answer. In meantime delete this 'answer'.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for pointing out I didn't answer the question correctly. Had a rough day. No need to be passive-agressive.